# Coloring cells based on two conditions in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I need to change the font color of cells into Red (column M) if it meets the two conditions:

1. Col P should have the text "waiting" AND
2. Col M's value should be greater than 1.0.

Can you please tell how to tackle this problem?

I tried the below code but it is not working:

```
Sub Latency()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    On Error GoTo ExitHere:
m = Range("A:B").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For r = 1 To m
    If Range("O" & r) = "*waiting* && Range("M" & r) >= 1 Then
        Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next r
ExitHere:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: syntax error in `If Range("O" & r) = "*waiting* && Range("M" & r) >= 1 Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `m`was off and I splitted your `if` statement

**EDIT:** The color change back to black was wrong, I updated my code.

```
Sub Latency()
Dim r As Long
Dim m As Long
On Error GoTo ExitHere:
m = Range("M:O").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For r = 1 To m
    If Range("O" & r) = "waiting" Then
        If Range("M" & r) >= 1 Then
            Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Else
        Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next r
ExitHere:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and I did not get any syntax error neither got the result. There was no coloring seen in the cells that matches this condition :(

Comment: works fine on my system... just to be sure: values are in col "M" and "waiting" is in col "O"

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code coloring of your code. It looks like you forgot to close the quote mark after `*waiting*`.